# Unable to find Mysql Database in DataBase Explorer of VIsual Studio Express 2012

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012, database-connection

i am using visual studio express 2012 and Mysql Server 5.0.I want to add Mysql Database provider in database explorer.

i installed **Mysql For VisualStudio 1.2.3" and then **Mysql connector/net 6.93**..But i get the same result as Previous..

I cant post images here due to some repution points in stackoverflow account..i have provided the image link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRlEg.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRhid.png

Please Do help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed MYSQL connector. Then just add a reference of MYSQL.DLL from the installed location of **MYSQL connector**. Then start using functions.

**STEP 1:**

Navigate to Solution Explorer -> And Right click on REFERENCE -> ADD reference.
http://uploadffs.nl/images/2014/09/23/kqK4p.jpg

**STEP 2:**

Now CLICK BROWSE -> Locate where you have installed MYSQL CONNECTOR PLUGIN. -> Most common pathway ... /directory/mysqlconnector/assemblies/v4.5

http://uploadffs.nl/images/2014/09/23/YA3Ot.jpg

**STEP 3:**

Now start using functions! 
`using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`

### Enjoy!!!

PS: Sorry mate I don't have enough reputation to display images!

Comment: Mate,the problems is not regarding the usage of functions of mysql..i want it on database explore which we sees for microsoft sql server